# Compiling using Java 6

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

Many of the users of my Java applets/applications don't have Java 7 installed (about 80%, surprisingly). If I compile my programs with Java 6,

- Will the Java 7 users be exposed to the security vulnerabilities in Java 6?
- Will my applet/application work with Java 6 **and** 7?
- Are there any disadvantages? I am not really using any of the new Java 7 features (except the diamond operator which is easily fixed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the Java 7 users be exposed to the security vulnerabilities in Java 6?

AFAIK, It's Java 7 which has the most serious security vulnerabilities.  How you compile the code doesn't matter, only what the code does and which JVM version you use.

> Will my applet/application work with Java 6 and 7?

If it has not bugs, yes.  If it has bugs, it is most likely to do the same thing on both, but possibly not. i.e. it might be that a bug appear in one version but no the other or in different ways on different versions.

> Are there any disadvantages? I am not really using any of the new Java 7 features (except the diamond operator which is easily fixed).

The disadvantage is just that you cannot use the new syntax or the new Java 7 libraries.

How the code runs or performs is not changed.

Comment: `It's Java 7 which has the most serious security vulnerabilities` Isn't a ton of people's justification of updating to get rid of security vulnerabilities?

Comment: @Doorknob java 7 had a high-profile vulnerability announced recently.  AFAIK that's been fixed in the most recent jvm, but the black eye remains.

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  Java 7 update 11 fixes the most serious known bug in Java 7 for applets. The bug was more serious than any I can remember (going back a few years ;)

Comment: @Doorknob - A change in version is usually for additional features. So usually it will contain bugs that need to be located in the wild, whereas the previous version will have years of bug fixes and less fancy features so be more secure and reliable. 6 had issues when it was released, 7 has issues now, 8 will have issues when it is released. I usually give a JVM about a year before I look at it, 2 before I consider adopting it.

Answer (score 0):

Security flaws have been discovered with both Java 7 and Java 6 when running in browser sandboxes; i.e. when running applets.  The most recent one was Java 7 only, but previous ones have applied to Java 6 or multiple versions.

The problem is that people who run your applets need to have Java enabled in their browsers.  And *that* makes them vulnerable to attack by people planting bad applets; e.g. on hacked 3rd party websites.

The best security advice we can give to users is to disable browser Java because of past and potential future vulnerabilities.  (On some platforms, a complete uninstall is advisable).  These measures will have the side-effect of rendering your applets useless.

IMO, you should be removing your applet functionality entirely rather than trying to make it work with multiple Java versions.

Comment: `removing your applet functionality` On a website for Java games? The applets are pretty much the whole point of the website...

Comment: @Doorknob - the point of your site is the games, not the implementation technology.  Use javascript.  Or migrate to JNLP.  Or just turn your site off.  Playing games is not a good reason to seriously compromise user security.

Comment: a.) I am using JNLP... b.) `Playing games is not a good reason to seriously compromise user security.` Really? http://www.google.com/search?q=java+games

Comment: 1) I didn't say "use JNLP".  I said "migrate to JNLP" ... as in recode all of your applets as JNPL-launched applications.  2) Sure people write games in Java, but that is beside the point.  We are talking about Applets here ... not Java in general.  And sure there are (ignorant) people who undertake risky activities like playing applet-based games ... but that doesn't mean that YOU should aid-and-abet their risk taking.

Comment: a.) My applets *are* JNLP-launched. b.) that's not really risky on a trusted website

Comment: The risk is that the user has Java enabled in his browser, and gets hacked when he visits an untrusted website.  I think you REALLY need to look more deeply into the nature of the most recent vulnerabilities.  Start by reading up on what advisories say the user needs to do to protect him / herself.  The problem is that a typical user DOES NOT UNDERSTAND the fine distinctions between how and where to install Java.

Comment: Chrome always asks to run applets. I think Firefox does too. If someone already has Java enabled (if they are ignorant, they definitely do) then my [wobsite](http://xkcd.com/148/) can't harm them.

Comment: If your website says something like "you need to install Java to play these games", then it is harmful.  Also, you are assuming that the user keeps his browser up to date.

Comment: So what you're saying is that Java applets are useless?

Comment: I am saying they are unsafe / dangerous / should not be used by "ordinary users" ... unless there is someone knowledgeable managing the user's PC security for him / her.  Obviously they are "useful" but then so is a loaded pistol with a broken safety catch ...

Comment: And just to reinforce the point - http://www.scmagazine.com.au/News/330453,java-still-unsafe-new-flaws-discovered.aspx